# Codeigniter checkbox returns always 0

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

I've a form to add a project with a checkbox if the project is already finished or not. This is the html in the view (codeigniter):

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label>Task completed:</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="task_completed" name="task_completed" />
                            <?php echo form_error('task_completed'); ?>

                        </div>
```

I load the data in my controller:

```
$checked = (int)$this->input->post('task_completed');
```

when i do a `echo "" . $checked;` it's always 0!!
Also, in my database. Where is my fault?

Comment: we're not doing math here `echo "" . $checked;` - `+` is a C/JS concatenation method. Plus, make sure there is an `int` value for it.

Comment: Thx guys, but the echo is not the fault. It's the checkbox. I will edit the + to .

Comment: If error reporting isn't set, see if this will https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html - you may need form tags with a POST method. If the checkbox is not an integer, remove `(int)`.

Comment: far as I can see, there is no value set for it.

Comment: Seeing no responses from my other comments, have moved on. Good luck.

Comment: You do not have any value check box input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the input name add `[]` like so

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="task_completed" name="task_completed[]" />
```

And try `$data = $this->input->post('task_completed');`

then `var_dump($data);`

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<label>Task completed:</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="task_completed" name="task_completed" value="1" />
```

And to verify if was checked, you can do something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="task_completed" name="task_completed" value="1" <?php echo $settings->task_completed ? 'checked' : ''; ?>
```

Basically get settings in models and send to view.

**Controller:**

```
 public function settings()
    {

        $data["settings"] = $this->admin_model->siteSettings();

        $this->load->view('settings', $data);
    }
```

**Model**

```
 public function siteSettings()
    {
        return $this->db->get('site_settings')->row();
    }
```

**View**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="task_completed" name="task_completed" value="1" <?php echo $settings->task_completed ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
```

Comment: Well, I have something similar w/ what u want. And, is working. If this is not the answer, I don't know what u want.